# Use rails test mixin methods from inside proc/lambda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I am trying to call the rails test methods from inside a lambda.  I get an error though saying method not defined.

```
actions = [
-> { post("url", body) },
-> { get("url") }
]

actions.each do |a|
 define 'test...'
   a.call() # undefined method 'post'
 end
end
```

The only way I can get to work is by manually creating test session and call methods off that. There are other tests in file that use the test helper methods but not from lambda, it makes tests confusing to have two last_respones, etc

```
session = Rack::Test::Session.new(Rack::MockSession.new(Sinatra::Application))
actions = [
-> { session.post("url", body) },
-> { session.get("url") }
]
```

Comment: Try `instance_exec(&a)` rather than `a.call` to transfer the scope

Comment: that worked, thanks!!